# iPhone Book Wrapper app, HTML pagination

Tags: iphone, html

i'm developing an app that will be just a wrapper for a certain book
the book is in HTML so, i want to make something like stanza,
i want to determine no. of pages given the Whole book HTML and to paginate that dynamically into views.

is there any built-in methods that can help me with that?
or
does anyone know any idea of how that can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do this once: insert some javascript into the HTML to tell you the height of the document once it's done loading, e.g.:

```
alert(document.height);
```

and divide that by the height of your web view to get the number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView to load the data, and leave the navigation/link code to paginate in the HTML.